# How do you use colored fonts in .lang files?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am making a custom texture pack with a .lang file, it looks something like this snippet:

```
enchantment.damage.all=Slayness
enchantment.damage.undead=Smite
enchantment.untouching=Silk Touch
enchantment.durability=Unbreaking
enchantment.lootBonus=Looting
enchantment.lootBonusDigger=Fortune
enchantment.lootBonusFishing=Luck of the Sea
enchantment.level.1=1
enchantment.level.10=Hax.
enchantment.level.127=Really?
```

I've tried to make colorful names like Making

```
enchantment.damage.all=Slayness
```

So it is this:

```
enchantment.damage.all=§4Slayness
```

Which, long story short, doesn't work.

Then I tried the `\u00A74 key` (Server MOTD):

```
enchantment.damage.all=\u00A74Slayness
```

## Question

Is there anyway to make one object name colored using `.lang files` in texture packs?

**UPDATE:** What happens when I try `enchantment.damage.all=§R§4Slayness`

[image: test]

Comment: According to http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Formatting_codes#Use_in_custom_language_packs, it should work. Maybe you need to add the `§r` to reset the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result in your image shows that the editor you're using is not encoding in UTF-8.

If you're using Window's Notepad, you will need to change the default encoding from ANSI to UTF-8 as you save the file.

[image: Notepad save screen]

If you're using [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), you can change the encoding from the *Encoding* menu.

[image: Notepad++ encoding menu]